# Get Function of Operator

Tags: php

In Python I can get a function for an operator from the standard library like this:

```
from operator import add
two = add(1, 1)
```

Is there a similar way to get an operator function in PHP, or do I have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: You refer to overload an operator function?

Comment: In PHP its no needed import from the standar library, all the "standrard" library is in the scope.

Comment: I'm not looking to overload. I wanted a function equivalent of the operation like `function ($l, $r) { return $l + $r; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement it from scratch.